# How can I stop the mesh from stretching when posing?

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, rigify

I'm trying to rig a model starting from a rigify metarig and it's been going pretty well. It looks like, though, the mesh is morphed and stretched everytime i pose it, which is a problem mainly for the head and hands. Is there a way to make these parts rotate while keeping their shape and size? Am I doing something wrong? (probably but still)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Blender.SE. "Wrong" distorsion are probably caused by incorrect weights. Are you familiar with weight painting and have examind the weights?

Comment: @Leander Yes, I did weight paint in what I assume is the right way for this model. From what I can gather weight painting only signifies where the mesh should be affected and not how, am I wrong? How should I weight paint so that this won't happen?

Comment: Well, the weights determine how much the mesh is affected by certain bones. Try changing (painting) the weights in the deformed pose and check if you can improve the deformation.

Comment: @Leander It doesn't seem to help much. There's an effect only when I paint an area completely "blue" aka unaffected, then it shoots back up in the default position. I think there's gotta be a different way to go about fixing that.

Comment: upload your file to www.blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com ?

Comment: The site you're suggesting won't upload the file for some reason. Here's a MediaFire link: http://www.mediafire.com/file/hdgosz9fyvf7q0g/yeeeee.blend/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the scale on your armature.

1. Select the armature and go to Object Mode.
2. Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *> Apply Scale*.

Comment: I tried it, but when I import it into the Unity project that it's for the model condenses into one big pile of limbs. It seems like the connections between the vertex groups are broken or something. What do I do from here?

Comment: @Scrillrock That sounds like another question. The deformation problem, described in this question, is solved by applying the scale, right?

Comment: It does seem to have done the job actually, so yes, sorry for that. I guess I'll mark your answer as accepted but any information on the deformation bit would be greatly appreciated. Great thank you for the help anyways, couldn't have figured it out myself!

Comment: When using matrix transformations from different object (like with an armature modifier), it is best to have the scale of all objects applied. If there are any specific subtopics, which are unclear or bothering, I think it would be best to include them in a detailed edit of the question. Also, feel free to open up a new question for a variation on the topic. You can link to this answer in a new question; and you open as many threads as you want.

Comment: Thanks, will do if needed!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146822/model-limbs-condensed-in-one-place-in-unity3d-after-applying-scale-to-armature

Answer (score 1):

When in *pose mode*, go to the rig main properties tab, and turn ik stretch for the feet and hands to zero. This will keep the mesh from stretching when posing.