# Model limbs condensed in one place in Unity3D after applying Scale to armature

Tags: mesh, armature, unity, vertex-groups

I'm new to Blender and modelling in general and I'm trying to incorporate a humanoid model I rigged into my Unity project. It was seemingly working fine in Unity up until I was given a solution to another question I posted here that had to do with the armature, which was that I had to apply scale to it. The problem was still there before that but the mesh looked as it should when not in motion. After applying the effect though, i get a message that the file has import settings and the model looks like this:

### [image]

The most definable features of this mess seem to be the thighs and head, which leads me to believe that the connections between the vertex groups are broken in some way. Maybe the armature has lost some property when I applied the scale effect? I'm really quite lost, any help would be appreicated.

Link to aforementioned question: [How can I stop the mesh from stretching when posing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146760/how-can-i-stop-the-mesh-from-stretching-when-posing/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I've figured it out myself. In Unity I changed the animation type from humanoid to generic and back while fiddling with the properties of the asset. This somehow seems to reset the model's import settings and it works fine now. Thought I'd leave this here for people with a similar problem in the future to see.